# JavaScript value not getting fetched undefined is coming

Tags: javascript

Why this code lines are not working

```
let a = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
let b = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1];
b.value = a;
```

A simple code to get value from one text and paste it into another text.

Comment: what does not working mean? Have you checked the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue code be that your code is running before the DOM is fully loaded. In that case you should get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

To solve the above issue either you can palce your code at the bottom of the *body* tag or wrap the code with [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event).

**Demo:**

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    let a=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
    let b=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1];
    b.value=a;
  });
</script>
<input value="123"/>
<input />
```

Comment: Thnks for reply I'm a beginner. It's not like python lines of code get executed , here you have used event listener and arrow function . But simply it can't work that value get copy paste

Comment: I put it on bottom of body tag only .

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can't get `input` element.
Why did you decided to get inputs by theirs tagname? Use id's or classes for getting it.
Second is, check it for availability at all.
for example:

```js
const [firstInput, secondInput] = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
if (firstInput && secondInput) {
    secondInput.value = firstInput.value || 'default value';
}
```

Something like that.

Comment: Here I'm getting value from index 0 text field and pasting in index 1 text field .

Comment: I understood it and wrote code which processes undefined values of inputs array. Questions? Yes, for avoid process events like `DOMContentLoaded`, please get used to put script tags in the end of body. This way you can avoid problems when JS doesn't know about DOM structure and can't extract elements.

Comment: Let's discuss it, what exactly doesn't work? I said, just move script tag to the end of body, end process inputs array availability. I don't see a problem.